# Not able to send email using javaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to execute a jar file which has java code to send an email. But when I run the jar, I don't get any email and also I don't get any exception. Below is the sample piece of code for authorization.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "xxx");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "FALSE");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "TRUE");
props.put("mail.stmp.user", "user");
props.put("mail.smtp.password", "pwd");

javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(
                "user@abc.com", "pwd");
    }
});
Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
simpleMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
simpleMessage.setSubject("Demo");
String message = "Hi";
simpleMessage.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
Transport.send(simpleMessage);
```

Can anyone please help in knowing where I'm going wrong. I was using fakeSMTP server to test previously and I used to receive mails in that tool. Later I have added authentication to use it in real time. But, I'm not able to achieve it.

I'm new to using javaMail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: is there any log of exception?

Comment: Can you post the server logs?

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Also, you can simplify your code by [getting rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0):

It could be external - have you checked your anti-virus log? On client if this is executing client-side or server AV log if your code is executing on server?

If that checks out, check your smtp server log.